# Lograr que menu item en android trabaje como un boton

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

Estoy por aca a ver si me orientan en este problema

Tengo un menu, con un item, y lo que quiero es dicho item trabaje como un boton, si se cliquea cambie el icono y un toast que diga Notificacion activas, y si se le da click nuevamente, cambien el icono y diga mediante toast, notificaciones Desactivadas.

Todo eso lo he logrado, el detalle esta en que al activar el boton y salir de la actividad y al volver entrar sale el boton nuevamente desactivado, cuando deberia de quedar activado

Espero entiendan, aca le dejo el codigo, que hace la funcion perfecta, pero creo que debo de realizar algo con shared preferencias para guardar si esta clickqueado o no, pero no se por donde arrancar, espero me entiendan y me orienten, Les dejo el codigo que he implementado

----- xml menu ------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_off_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/notificaciones"
        android:id="@+id/notificaciones"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"
    />


</menu>
```

--------- Java---------------

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menucampeonatos, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.notificaciones);
        item.setChecked(false);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.notificaciones);
        checkable.setChecked(false);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.notificaciones:

                if (item.isChecked()){
                    myRef.update("notificacion", false);

                    item.setChecked(false);
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_off_black_24dp);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Notificaciones Desactivadas para este campeonato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    myRef.update("notificacion", true);

                    item.setChecked(true);
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_black_24dp);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Notificaciones Activadas para este campeonato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Sale desactivado porque en onCreate estás desactivándolo. Así que cada vez que se crea la actividad, saldrá desactivado. Tendrías que guardar el estado para poder actualizarlo al último que tuviera en vez de establecerlo siempre como desactivado.

Comment: Hola súper y alguna sugerencia de como plantear lo que me recomiendas

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar el estado de tu boton con shared preferences usa los metodos de ciclo de vida de tu activity, puedes usar onPause u onDestroy y cargar el estado desde onCreateOptionsMenu

```
private boolean btnChecked;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menucampeonatos, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.notificaciones);
    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Obtiene el valor guardado, o false si el valor no existe
    btnChecked=sp.getBoolean("notificaciones",false);
    item.setChecked(btnChecked);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.notificaciones);
    //checkable.setChecked(false);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.notificaciones:

                if (item.isChecked()){
                    myRef.update("notificacion", false);
                    btnChecked=false
                    item.setChecked(false);
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_off_black_24dp);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Notificaciones Desactivadas para este campeonato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    myRef.update("notificacion", true);
                    btnChecked=true
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_active_black_24dp);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Notificaciones Activadas para este campeonato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("notificaciones",btnChecked);
        editor.apply();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```